# Score calculation with Javascript

Tags: javascript

As the title suggests. How do I do this?

Im bound to use pure JS, and i'm realy new to it (like realy realy new). So please excuse my noob question. :)

My code looks like this :

```
if (questionArr[questionId].choices[k].tf === true) {
   score = score + questionArr[questionId].choices[k].points; //add points if answer is correct
} else {
   if ((score - questionArr[questionId].choices[k].points) > 0) {
       score = score - questionArr[questionId].choices[k].points; //subtract points if answer is wrong
   } else {
      score = 0;
   }
}
```

My problem is the following: Lets say the question has 4 answers, first one gives 5 points, 2nd one is wrong, subtracts 6 points, 3rd one is wrong subtracts 3 points and the 4th one is correct giving 10 points.

So I want to end up with 6 points in the end, because:

```
+5 -6 -3 = -4
-4 +10 = 6
```

Unfortunatly it seems that when i run it, my code is either cutting of the number im guessing when it reaches 0. Which prevents me from calculation the score when the points go below 0. In the end if the total score stays below 0 i want it to be set to 0 automatically, thats what im trying to do with the else at the end.

I hope someone can help me with this, cause i dont quite know how to solve this.

Comment: I think you need to add a bit more code, what is `k`? Perhaps calculate the score without concerning yourself with negative numbers and then after the loop (I'm guessing here, you're iterating through all questions using `k`?) check if the number is negative.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need to move the if statement outside of the code that's (presumably) looping through all the questions.  ie:

```
//guessing start of for loop that sets questionId and k
if (questionArr[questionId].choices[k].tf === true) {
    score = score + questionArr[questionId].choices[k].points; //add points if answer is correct
} else {
    score = score - questionArr[questionId].choices[k].points; //subtract points if answer is wrong
}
//end of loop
if (score < 0) score = 0;
```